# C# Objects pointing to null even when instantiated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, object, nullreferenceexception

- I have a public class called Game that is static.
- In the class I have two private pointer variables cards and hands[].

In the class I also have a static game() method that instantiate the two pointers to point them to their class instance object.

**The problem: The properties/pointers are showing green underline in Visual Studios and when debugging it says the objects are null. I don't understand?**`

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
public static class Game {
    private static Card card;
    private static Hand[] hands;

   public static void Game() {

       Card card = new Card(true);
       Hand[] hands = new Hand[2];
   }
}
```

`

Comment: You are defining locals `card` and `hands` that are hiding the fields.

Answer (score 4):

First, your code will not compile, as you can't have a static method whose name is the same as the enclosing type.

But let's assume you are trying to use a static constructor.  If so, you are declaring method level variables of `card` and `hands`. If you want to use the class member fields, then you simply do not include the type when assigning the variable.  For example:

```
static Game()
{
    card = new Card(true);
    hands = new Hand[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Card card = ...` creates a local variable called card. It doesn't do anything to the class-level 'card'.

Change

```
Card card = new Card(true);
Hand[] hands = new Hand[2];
```

to

```
card = new Card(true);
hands = new Hand[2];
```